# F# .net framework with visual studio code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

Is there any site or book explaining how to compile for .net framework, writing F# code in visual studio code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile for .NET Framework using the .NET Core SDK, actually. You just need to indicate that in your project file (*.fsproj). Where it says something like this:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

put this instead:

```
<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
```

(or a lower number if you need to target an older framework)

Answer (score 1):

The [Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools SKU](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017), does not install Visual Studio. It just installs MSBuild and various other compiler toolchains.

Simply select F# from the Individual Components tab (or on the right-hand side in the MSBuild workload) and press Install.

The installation location will be: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp`

[Use F# on Windows](https://fsharp.org/use/windows/)

---

1. [How to use F# in command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line) with link to an installer and a short usage example.
2. [How to install ionide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-vscode) with examples.

Comment: Thanks but that refers to dot net core and I would like to write code for the dot net framework.